# Does teradata provides free or trial setup of multinode (at least 2 node) environment

Tags: teradata

I want to test my code on Teradata on 2 node environment. It doesn't need a power of multiple AMPs multiple nodes ( more than 2 ).
Like Teradata provides VM of single node setup of its every version, 
does it provide vm for 2 node setup

Answer (score 1):

Teradata Express is a single node 2 AMP only VM, but there's the free [Teradata on VMware Developer Tier](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/database/teradata-on-vmware-developer-tier) running on VMware ESXi which supports up to 2 nodes.

Or you could check Teradata on AWS & Azure, there's some free version, too, I don't know if they support multiple nodes.

But the main question is:

Why do you think you need that for testing? There's absolutely no difference if you got a single node or a multi node system.

Comment: I need to test install script on multiple node